# how to get a list of folders and number files in each folder side by side, in the current directory?

Tags: command-line, files

I am at the directory: 
`/home/john/my_test_files/`
and under the directory there are 100 folders:

```
folder1
folder2
folder3
...
folder100
```

what command would I use to print the list of folders and the each one's file count side by side. Something like this:

```
folder1     25
folder2     78
folder3     34
...
folder100   88
```

where `folder1` has 25 files in it, `folder2` has 78 files in it, etc

I'm sure this is something basic but I couldn't find a good answer...

Answer (score 4):

Here is one relatively slow solution, that provides a nice output :) Place the following function at the bottom of your `~/.bashrc` file. Then open new terminal window or do source the run commands file: `. ~/.bashrc`.

```bsh
count_in() {
    # set the current directory as default value
    local paths="$PWD"; echo
    # read the user's input as array when it is provided
    [[ ! -z ${@+x} ]] && local paths=( "$@" )

    # loop over the user's input
    for path in "${paths[@]}"
    do
        # test whether this is a directory
        [[ ! -d $path ]] && { echo -e "'$path' is not a directory.\n"; break; }

        # output color table header for each top level directory
        printf '\e[1;34m%-6s%-6s%-6s%s\e[m\n' "total" "files" "dirs" "analyzed directory"
        # analyse the top level data
        total=$(find "$path/" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 | wc -l)
        files=$(find "$path/" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l)
        dirs=$(find "$path/" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | wc -l)
        # outpot the top level data
        printf '%-6d%-6d%-6d%s\n' "$total" "$files" "$dirs" "$path"

        # output color table separator for the inner directories
        printf '\e[1;96m%-6s%-6s%-6s%s\e[m\n' "total" "files" "dirs" "sub dir name"
        # for each inner directory
        while IFS='' read -r dir
        do
                # analyse a inner directory's data
                total=$(find "$dir" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 | wc -l)
                files=$(find "$dir" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l)
                dirs=$(find "$dir" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | wc -l)
                # outpot the inner directory's data
                printf '%-6d%-6d%-6d%s\n' "$total" "$files" "$dirs" "$(basename "$dir")"
        done <<< $(find "$path/" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -print)
        echo
    done
}
```

Then use the `count_in` function as shell command:

```bsh
count_in  # will analyse the current directory
count_in  /path1 /path2
```

Sample output:

```bsh
spas@Desktop:~$ count_in Pictures ~/Videos 'Something else'

total files dirs  analyzed directory
9     3     6     Pictures
total files dirs  sub dir name
19    19    0     Life Hacks
6     6     0     GIF
55    54    1     Wallpapers
20    18    2     Avatars
173   31    142   Photos
3     2     1     Icons

total files dirs  analyzed directory
6     0     6     /home/spas/Videos
total files dirs  sub dir name
66    0     66    Movies
11    0     11    Documentary.and.Conspiracy
7     7     0     .fun
16    2     14    Science.and.SciFi
2     2     0     Fun
2     1     1     Audio.Books

'Something else' is not a directory.
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`du -s --inodes *` comes to mind (`--inodes` option is only available in newer ubuntu versions, I believe in 16.04 and newer). This will print something like

```
4       logs
1       pom.xml
140     src
323     target
```

The number in front of the directory/file names is the number of files and directories inside the directory including the directory itself.

To illustrate the number we have a look at `logs` directory.

```
$ find logs
logs
logs/2019-11-17-2.log.gz
logs/latest.log
logs/2019-11-17-1.log.gz
$ find logs | wc -l
4
```

You see the directory contains 3 files plus the directory itself gives 4, as seen in `du` output.

Please be aware that counting lines in `find` output is not a reliable way to determine number of files as file names containing newlines would count twice. In my simple example it is no problem, but in your case this method might not be reliable. `du` works regardless of any special characters in file names.

Answer (score 3):

It depends a bit what you mean by *files*

If you want to count all the non-hidden items (files / directories / symlinks) - the same as you would see with a simple `ls` command - you could do a shell loop like this:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for d in */; do set -- "$d"/*; printf '%s\t%d\n' "$d" "$#"; done
```

This uses a `*` glob to expand a list of items in each directory, plus the `set` shell builtin to assign the result to the list of the shell's positional parameters - whose count is available in special variable `$#`

If you don't want the trailing slash in the output, change `"$d"`in the print statement to `"${d%/}". To pretty-print the results, pipe them through`column -t`:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for d in */; do set -- "$d"/*; printf '%s\t%d\n' "${d%/}" "$#"; done | column -t
```

You can include hidden items by setting the `dotglob` shell option.